# How to speed up react-native start?

Tags: react-native

I created a react native app with `react-native init`.

Then i run the command `react-native start` and it stays for 20 minutes at `Loading dependency graph` step before displaying `Loading dependency graph, done.`

How to speed up the `Loading dependency graph` step ?

(i'm on windows 10 and try to run the app on my own device)

Comment: That's definitely strange behaviour. Even for loaded apps it usually builds up less than a minute. Have you tried to do it several times with the same result?

Comment: Yes I tried at least 10 times and got the same result